# Testing in Rails3.1 is very slow. Is there some sort of solution to load the tests faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rails-3.1

I am assuming that the tests are loading slower because of the asset pipeline. I am wondering if there is some sort of gem, or magical spell that I can use to make the tests load faster. rake test:units takes forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways. A popular one right now is [Spork](http://spork.rubyforge.org/), which avoids loading the entire Rails stack multiple times.

There's also [Parallel Test](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests), which runs multiple test suites in parallel (taking advantage of the multiple cores/processors on your machine).

Comment: Sadly simplecov does not work with spork, but you can always run it without spork running once in a while to get stats.